# If I use http-server with node can other devices on my network access it?

Tags: node.js, httpserver

**Background**

I am building a site using angularjs and want to make sure that its displaying properly on my phone. I'm aware of the Google Chrome emulator but would like to show people it directly on the phone.

**Node.JS**

I'm using `http-server .` to run a server at the base of my app. This was the quickest and easiest way of getting a server for local testing.

I have tried going onto the same network via wifi on my phone and then trying to get to `localhost:8080` but it just gives me a "this web page is not available" error

**Question**

My question is, is there a way to get my web app on my phone with `http-server .` or do I need to set up a proper web-server? I thought maybe it would just be simple to get it on any device attached to the same network.

Comment: Instead of `localhost`, try with the ip address of the machine in which app is running.

Comment: @MohitPandey you were correct, thanks. if you put up an answer I will accept it, mention that it has to be the device ip not your public ip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since our application(server) and devices(in which you want to access the application) running on same network.

You can access this with the help of IP address.

Let say, your app is running on

```
192.168.1.1:3000
```

So you can access it as `localhost:3000` on local machine.

And as `192.168.1.1:3000` on devices which is using the same network.

Answer (score 0):

any device can access to server. Use ip in device not use localhost

Answer (score 0):

Use ngrok https://ngrok.com/ , ngrok expose your localhost behind a NAT or firewall to the internet , easy to use , after install just type on command line ;

```
ngrok 7070
```

**then it gives you a link like ;** 3g87g9g.ngrok.com

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifconfig` utility if you are in linux or use any other tool to get the ip address of your phone (Web server), for example `192.168.1.10` is IP address of the phone.

You can access the web page from any other device in the network by going to `192.168.1.10:8080` in the browser.

Note that `8080` is the port to your server application, you select the port from node.js